# Wordpress: How to make working in an other path

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess

I want to change the URL of my site from

domain.com/**wordpress**/post-name

in

domain.com/**blog**/post-name

I changed the "Site Address (URL)" in General Setting in "/blog"

than as written here 
http://codex.wordpress.org/Giving_WordPress_Its_Own_Directory#Using_a_pre-existing_subdirectory_install

**1 - I edited the htaccess in root...**

RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www.)?YourDomain.com$
RewriteRule ^(/)?$ blog [L]

**2 - Created the folder "blog"**
copied htaccess from wordpress directory
copied the index.php

changed in the index this part....
require( dirname( **FILE** ) . '/wp-blog-header.php' );

in this part: 
require( dirname( **FILE** ) . '/wordpress/wp-blog-header.php' );

**3 -saved permalinks to update the htaccess (updated manually too)**

**THE PROBLEM**

The redirection is ok. 
but there is a white page... 
my question is it's correct this part? 
require( dirname( **FILE** ) . '/wordpress/wp-blog-header.php' );

the folders are both in the root

/wordpress

/blog

or should be something like 
require( dirname( **FILE** ) . '../wordpress/wp-blog-header.php' );  ?

thank you for any help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`require( dirname( FILE )` will return the current directory.

So this `require( dirname( FILE ) . '/wordpress/wp-blog-header.php' );` will return `'blog/wordpress/wp-blog-header.php'`

Just use `require('../wordpress/wp-blog-header.php');`

Comment: Thank you very much it work perfectly!



So to change wordpress directory/folder in URL without change the installation path this is the right way.

Comment: Giving WordPress a different directory Change Directory for Wordpress SOLVED Thank you Magesh.

Read the 3 steps and the Magesh Fix and it's done.

The wordpress administration remain in the original path like for example yourdomain.com/wordpress/wp-admin/

I wrote here because I did not find the right solution anywhere.

Comment: Glad to know that my answer works for you. Please accept my answer. See this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24090866/change-wordpress-admin-url