# If I change WP ADMIN URL will it make it harder to hack? How do I change WP ADMIN URL?

Tags: wordpress, phpmyadmin, admin

I want to make it more difficult for hackers to find my WP ADMIN URL.

How do I change the WP ADMIN URL? I don't want site.com/wp-admin to work at all.

Thank you.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Change Wordpress Admin URL](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24090866/change-wordpress-admin-url)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [All In One WP Security & Firewall](https://wordpress.org/plugins/all-in-one-wp-security-and-firewall/) and change the login URL to whatever you want. There are several options to secure your wordpress from hackers.