# Changing wp-admin url to something else?

Tags: php, wordpress

I like to change the wordpress wp-admin URL to something else to save my site from bruteforce attacks.

Most important thing is that i like to build this without plugin.

So, if anyone have any idea then do lemme know.

I applied changes as per the below links:
https://w3reign.com/how-to-change-wp-admin-url-in-wordpress-without-plugin/

but it's working but when i fire the http://site_url/admin_url  it's showing wp-login.php.

So, how can i do so ?

Comment: The answers here might be of use: [Change Wordpress Admin URL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24090866/change-wordpress-admin-url)

Comment: used this plugin https://wordpress.org/plugins/wps-hide-login/ it working fine

Comment: Sorry @AnkurBhadania , i want to achieve this without plugin.

Comment: 5.   Restrict the /wp-loging.php file:
Now if someone tries access via /wp-login.php url, it will show 404 page.


Follow the fifth step shown on 

https://w3reign.com/how-to-change-wp-admin-url-in-wordpress-without-plugin/

Answer (score 0):

1. Create a new file in your WP root folder.
2. Copy the code from default wp-login.php and paste it into your new file.
3. Replace all the instaces of wp-login.php with the new file name(Find and replace)
4. Delete/rename the wp-login.php file.
5. Login through your new URL.

Hope it helps.
For detail, use [this](https://www.elegantthemes.com/blog/resources/how-to-obscure-your-sites-login-page-without-a-plugin)

Comment: He wants to change `wp-admin` part of URL

Comment: Finally i did it...
    add_filter( 'login_url', 'my_login_page', 10, 2 );
    function my_login_page( $login_url, $redirect ) {

 if(stristr($redirect,"admin")){
  wp_safe_redirect('/site_url/404.php');
 }else{
  return str_replace("wp-login.php","custom_url_string",$login_url); 
 }
}

    add_action( 'login_form', 'replace_login_submit_form',1); 
    function replace_login_submit_form() {
       $your_content = ob_get_contents();
      $your_content = str_replace("wp-login.php","custom_url_string",$your_content);  
     ob_get_clean();
      echo $your_content;
    }