# Wordpress Change all URL of admin panel

Tags: php, wordpress

I want to change the admin url of my Wordpress website from `http://website.com/wp-admin/` to `http://website.com/mainadmin1990/` . I have searched and tried, but didn’t get any solution which  can change the whole admin url. The plugin or solution which is available its only for changing the admin login url not admin url.

Please let me know any solution or plugin is available to change the Wordpress admin URL.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Change Wordpress Admin URL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24090866/change-wordpress-admin-url)

Comment: No this solution is not working and I want to change all admin URL not only the login page URL.

Comment: The link in the first answer says 'Now your admin URL will be like: http://www.yourdomain.com/secret-folder/'. I thought that was what you wanted?

Answer (score 1):

Please find below the solution worked for me.

https://wordpress.org/plugins/hide-my-wp/

Please note that you will have to test the website functionalities thoroughly after the installation.