# Unwanted redirection to wp-admin directory

Tags: wordpress

I have installed the admin folder of Wordpress inside another directory called "painel" for security reasons.

Now the url is mydomain.com/painel/wp-admin.

However when I type the old URL mydomain.com/wp-admin it redirects to the new one mydomain.com/painel/wp-admin. This is the opposite behavior I am looking for. I specifically want that when someone types mydomain.com/wp-admin it redirects to a 404 error page.

I checked my .htaccess file and it seems that the redirection rule isn't there. But I'm very ignorant on that matter.

Here it is:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www.)?mydomain.com$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/painel/
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /painel/$1
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www.)?mydomain.com$
RewriteRule ^(/)?$ painel/index.php [L] 
</IfModule>


<IfModule mod_headers.c>
  <FilesMatch "\.(ttf|ttc|otf|eot|woff|woff2|font.css|css|js)$">
    Header set Access-Control-Allow-Origin "*"
  </FilesMatch>
</IfModule>
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>

# END WordPress
```

Any idea of how I can stop the redirection?

Comment: Unless you are trying to do it just to learn wordpress I'll advice you to use some plugin for that, there are bunch of them. Also, you may check some answers [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24090866/change-wordpress-admin-url)

Comment: Thank you for your reply @GMarco24. The answers on the topic you linked show how to redirect to the wp-admin folder using functions. I want the opposite of that. If possible I would like to fix it by myself since I avoid using unnecessary plugins.

Comment: Actually hiding url not to match `URL/wp-admin` is what improves security. Why do you think moving folder to another place is much better?