# Changing wp-admin url to be same as site url

Tags: php, wordpress

I've added in wp-config.php following lines:

```
    define('WP_HOME','https://beta.example.com');
    define('WP_SITEURL','https://example.com');
```

I want to display admin panel as https://example.com/wp-admin, not https://beta.example.com/wp-admin, how to do that?

Thank you.

Comment: Take a look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24090866/change-wordpress-admin-url. That shows you how to put your admin area in a separate folder. You could then mess with your virtual hosts file to make this folder accessible from a different domain.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to do this via a **redirect** on your server.

WP_SITEURL and WP_HOME is for when your Wordpress installation is in a folder as opposed to directly in the root.

Hope that helps.