# Replace the /wp-admin with /dashboard inside custom theme functions.php in WordPress

Tags: php, wordpress, function

Is there a way I can add a php script into my custom theme's file to have default Wordpress login page **/wp-admin** changed to **/dashboard** would there be a way to do this solely inside my themes functions.php file?

Someone told me that this needs to be done inside .htaccess file but thought there was a way around this, etc??

Thank-you.

Answer (score -1):

Perhaps one of the answers [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24090866/change-wordpress-admin-url/35474835) will work for you?

While your `functions.php` file can technically run whatever code you want it to, it's bad practice to include such functionality in a theme. I would recommend using [an existing](https://wordpress.org/plugins/change-wp-admin-login/) *plugin* or making your own.

Comment: I so appreciate your suggestion but I really don't want to rely on plugins as this theme will be used in multiple sites and wanted a one stop solution.

Comment: @ShrockCo You can use `is_plugin_active()` and similar functions to check if a plugin is active and prevent a theme from activating. That way, whoever uses it will be forced to install the plugin so you can ensure all sites are using it.

Comment: That is a great thought, however I would have to go to each individual site and make sure that the url is set to /dashboard then and while I could do that for a whole suite of sites it would be a bit cumbersome for us.